# T-SQL Task generator script

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, task

I need to create a **T-SQL** (I`m using **SQL Server 2008 Express**) script (**procedure/function**) that takes entries from a "**Tasks**" table and generates only the tasks planned to occur in the next 5 hours.

In the "Tasks" table I should have tasks with **job** like properties :

- **Occurrence** : One time or Recursive
- **Frequency**  : every x **Days, Weeks, Months**
- Depending on the **Frequency** :
- For **Daily** : every x **hours,minutes**
- For **Weekly**  -**Days of the week** when the task should occur
- For **Monthly** - The **first,second,last** -day,week day,weekend -
  day of week **OR** The 1st, 2nd, 3rd..31st of the **month**.

When I run the script I should get only the tasks that will occur in the next 5 hours or less in the case if task occurs every x **minutes**.
So what this script should actually do is use all the options from a SQL Server Job for a task.

**Example1**: I create a task "Check email" that occurs **every day**, between 14:00 and 15:00 . When i run the script at 09:00 I would get Task:"Check email" Time:5 hours left until task, because it occurs every day, i should be able to get this result every day when I roll the script ,only if that 5 hours or less range .

**Example2**: A task "Send hours report" that occurs **Monthly**, on the 1st week day (not weekend), at 01:00 PM . Running the script on the first week day of the month at 08:00 AM I should get Task:"Send hours report" Time:5 hours until task

I know it's a quite big request but hopefully someone will find it easy what for me seems pretty hard.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Are you asking about sql jobs? Or is this some sort of thing you are writing that will implement the same type of scheduling as a number of other things available? If it is the latter I would ask why you can't use a premade scheduler. As you are discovering it is pretty darn complicated.

Comment: Not asking about sql jobs, it`s an alternative for jobs. A premade schedule is a good ideea. I need the script to see the tasks that are scheduled for the next 5 or less hours.

Answer (score 0):

You should also store somewhere the date/time of the last execution of each job (at least for jobs that are configured for every x hours/minutes). The idea is to calculate the next execution date/time for each job, and return it if it's less than 5 hours away. If the job is configured for every x hours/minutes, use DATEADD and check if the result is within the configured timeframe. If the job is configured for daily (at a specified time), just check if the specified time is less than 5 hours away (but still in the future). I have done a similar feature and it's not an easy thing to check for all cases (it took me a few days of coding).

Comment: I will make an execution queue for that. For the tasks that occur weekly or monthly in specific week days or the first,second to last day of the month is what I find more difficult.